# Is there a way to search two different collection and fill another collection using LINQ?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I have two different collections like below

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }      
}

public class Skills
{
    public int SkillID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Keyskill_Name { get; set; }        
    public int LastUsedYear { get; set; }
}
```

Here one student can contain multiple keyskils

I just want to fill a new collection like below

```
public class StudentDetails
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public list<string> Keyskill_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the source of your data? Linq to sql/entities/ other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GroupJoin` LINQ method is the perfect solution for this case:

```
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    List<Skills> skills = new List<Skills>();

    List<StudentDetails> studentDetails = students.GroupJoin(skills, student => student.StudentID, skill => skill.StudentID, (student, skillsForStudent) => new StudentDetails
    {
        FirstName = student.FirstName,
        LastName = student.LastName,
        StudentID = student.StudentID,
        Keyskill_Name = (from skill in skillsForStudent
                         select skill.Keyskill_Name).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

#### How to use the `GroupJoin` method?

- Call the method from the set that gives a 1 to 1 relation with the result (Here for each `Student`, there is one and only one corresponding `StudentDetails`.
- The first argument of the method is the set you want to "distribute" on the other items (Here the skills are "distributed" over the entire set of students)
- The second and third arguments are used to explain how to make the collision between the elements of the first set and the elements of the second set. Lambda expressions are extremely useful in this case.
- Lastly, the fourth argument, is used to define the result. It is a function with 2 parameters : an element of the first set (here `students`) and its corresponding elements in the second set that have been found using the collision.

Comment: `where skill.StudentID == student.StudentID` is not necessary.

Comment: Was, that's quite true given it is the purpose of the Join in GroupJoin ;). Thanks. I've edited the post to correct it.